# Nearest branch numbering

Tags: nomenclature

If the longest carbon chain is symmetric numbering-wise (meaning the numbering schemes are identical both ways) and has all alkyl substituents, should one prioritize the largest alkyl group?

Comment: I am not sure what is your concern here, but if you are asking about naming a compound like $\ce{CH3CH2CH(CH3)(CH2)_4CH(C2H5)CH2CH3}$, I believe the priority is alphabetical (i.e ethyl>methyl), and hence this compound will be *3-ethyl 8-methyl decane.*

Comment: Thanks - that's what I what I was looking for. I was confused about if one should take into consideration the size of the substituent.

Answer (score 3):

If numbering from each end of the parent chain gives the same locants, the next criterion stipulates that lowest locants are assigned to the substituent that is cited first as a prefix in the name. This means in effect that alphanumerical order is used to establish the numbering when a choice is possible since alphanumerical order is used to establish the order of citation of substituent prefixes in the name.

On this matter, the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)* reads as follows:

> **P-14.4** NUMBERING
>
> When several structural features appear in cyclic and acyclic compounds, low locants are assigned to them in the following decreasing order of seniority:
>
> (…)
>
> (f) detachable alphabetized prefixes, all considered together in a series of increasing numerical order;
>
> (g) lowest locants for the substituent cited first as a prefix in the name;
>
> (…)

Note that Rule f takes precedence over Rule g. If no decision can be attained by application of P-14.4(f), the lowest set of locants is selected according to P-14.4(g) in their order of their citation in the name.

For example, a correct systematic name is **4-ethyl-5-methyloctane** (not 5-ethyl-4-methyloctane) since ethyl is cited first as a prefix in the name.

[image: 4-ethyl-5-methyloctane]

Another correct systematic name is **4-ethyl-5-propyloctane** (not 5-ethyl-4-propyloctane). Again, the reason is that ethyl is cited first as a prefix in the name. The size of the substituent is not relevant in this step.

[image: 4-ethyl-5-propyloctane]